# Replace elements in array if a condition meet

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to optimize my function with numpy.
I have an array[x, y, 4] which is a RGBA image (obtained from `bgra = cv2.cvtColor(bgra, cv2.COLOR_RGB2RGBA)`)

I want to do something like this:

```
        for pixel_row in bgra:
            for pixel in pixel_row:
                if pixel[0] == 0:
                    pixel[3] = 0
```

or this:

```
        for pixel_row in bgra:
            for pixel in pixel_row:
                if np.array_equal([0,0,0,255], pixel):
                    pixel[3] = 0
```

but using numpy which is wide faster than manual iterations.
I tried this

```
bgra = np.where(bgra == [0,0,0,255], [0,0,0,0], bgra)
```

but the result is not what I expected because each value of the pixel is compared and replaced individually. I want to make black pixels fully transparent.

Comment: could you include a sample?

Comment: `bgra = np.where(np.array_equal(bgra, [0,0,0,255]), [0,0,0,0], bgra)` could try this

Comment: There's a opencv function as well: https://answers.opencv.org/question/97416/replace-a-range-of-colors-with-a-specific-color-in-python/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.all(axis=2)` to enforce the condition on the color channel axis. Then you can use `np.where` to update the color channel axis:

```py
import numpy as np
  
img = np.zeros((3, 3, 4))
img[..., 3] = 255
img[1, 1] = [1, 2, 3, 255]

new = img.copy()
new[...,3] = np.where((img == [0,0,0,255]).all(axis=2), 0, img[...,3])

print(img, new, sep='\n\n')
```

The output is:

```
[[[  0.   0.   0. 255.]
  [  0.   0.   0. 255.]
  [  0.   0.   0. 255.]]

 [[  0.   0.   0. 255.]
  [  1.   2.   3. 255.]
  [  0.   0.   0. 255.]]

 [[  0.   0.   0. 255.]
  [  0.   0.   0. 255.]
  [  0.   0.   0. 255.]]]

[[[  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]]

 [[  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  1.   2.   3. 255.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]]

 [[  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.]]]
```